# Problems using a composite view in Titanium Alloy

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I am trying to implement a simple app in Alloy that has a very basic structure but I cannot get it to layout reliably. I am trying to bottom align a group of navigation buttons with a working area above them which in the following example would be a TableView.

```
<Alloy>
<Collection src="book">
<Window height="100%" id="main" title="My Library {opts.username}" exitOnClose="true" onOpen="loadExtras">
    <TableView id="content" dataCollection="book" top="10px" bottom="100px" onDragEnd="refreshTable">
        <TableViewRow title="{title}" color="black" onClick="showBook"/>
    </TableView>
    <View bottom="0px" height="72px" layout="horizontal" id="actionPanel">
        <Button class="footerBtn" onClick="refreshTable">View</Button>
        <Button class="footerBtn" onClick="refreshTable">Help</Button>
        <Button class="footerBtn" onClick="refreshTable">List</Button>
        <Button class="footerBtn add" onClick="addBook"></Button>   
    </View>
</Window>
```

The only way I can get this to work is to specify a height for the TableView such as height="80%" and then play with this value until things layout as I would prefer but I do not want to do as I need this to work independently of the devices physical screen size.

How can I implement this kind of layout in Alloy to get a view to pin to the bottom of the screen with a variable working area above it - or, do I have to assume a standard height and work relative to that?

Answer (score 0):

Try pinning the table to the bottom of the parent view and then setting the height to be 80% of the parent view height. Also, use `dp` values to be screen independent.

```
<TableView id="content" height="80%" bottom="100dp" 
           onDragEnd="refreshTable"
           dataCollection="book">
```

Comment: Thanks - The issue turned out to be a rogue declaration in app.tss setting all Window elements to a default layout of vertical. Alloy ignores any absolute positioning in this case which is why I was unable to pin the view to the bottom. When I changed it to composite, all worked as expected.